# Order / Invoicing best practices: Store net / gross / VAT or calculate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-structures, database-design

I am hoping someone could help on this.

I am updating an ordering / despatch and invoicing system.

I have a OrderItem table which includes the following (truncated for ease):

- OrderItemId (PK)
- OrderId
- ProductId
- UnitPrice
- Qty
- VatCodeId (FK)

The net, gross, total and VAT fields are calculated when required.

I have always used this method but now I am thinking that the values should be stored in the OrderItemTable, as such:

- OrderItemId (PK)
- OrderId
- ProductId
- UnitNet
- UnitVat
- UnitGross
- LineNet
- LineVat
- LineGross
- Qty
- VatCodeId (FK)

I realise this table is now not normalised but speaking to someone in the field, they have quite successfully convinced me that this is historical data which should *never* be changed and as such, should be stored at the time of posting. I am inclined to believe them.

Performance wise, I do not think it will make much difference either way but may make reporting slightly easier.

Could I be so cheeky as to ask some of you experts your opinion?

Many thanks in advance, as usual!

Comment: If you want the ability to report historical information, then you need to store all calculated fields, because tax rates could change. If you just store gross today, when the tax rate is, say 8%, and then the tax rate changes to 10% two years from now, then all reports for transactions that occurred prior to the change will be wrong. And you don't want to store just gross and tax rate, because tax calculations might change: it might be something other than a straight percentage.

Comment: Dear Jim, many thanks for the reply. I store the VatCodeId which is your tax code in the US.  This enables historical tax information to be stored for each Order / OrderItem.
Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you do, have users and client programs access views and stored procedures, *not base tables*. That way, you can change what you store and what you compute without any fuss. This is one of the key features of relational DBMSs.

Bear in mind that if you introduce redundancy (by storing "everything") without controlling it with constraints, you *will* end up with inconsistent data. Rules belong in the database.

If your rules are currently simple (i.e. VatCodeId determines VAT (and changes if the VAT changes), UnitGross = UnitNet + UnitVat and so on), your system will be simplest and most reliable if you avoid redundancy and store only the minimum. It is a simple matter to create a view that looks as if you store everything, and use this for reporting, UIs etc.

If the rules subsequently change, change the base table(s) (and use the simple rules to populate the new columns), and redefine views and stored procedures to account for the table changes (without changing their headers/signatures, preferrably). This saves you from database schema complexity you might never need.

Answer (score 4):

I *strongly* recommend storing the calculated values of all fields, because tax rates and calculations change. That includes net, gross, VAT, and total. The reason is because the calculations could change at any time.

For example, imagine today that the tax rate is 10%. You make a sale of 10 units at $10 each. So gross is $100. You calculate tax, subtract 10%, and your net is now $90.

But two years from now, tax rate goes to 13%. Are you going to modify your reporting programs so that they calculate the tax differently for older transactions? Having done this in the past, I'll bet you get it wrong somewhere. You'll have to change dozens, or perhaps hundreds, of reporting programs. You're bound to miss a few, and you won't find all of them for *years*. Save yourself the headache: store everything you'll need. Don't depend on the ability to calculate tomorrow the things you calculated today.

Also note that things other than rates can change. They might change which items are taxable. They might add graduated tax rates, or make you compute two different kinds of taxes, or ... believe me, lots of different things change. In the U.S., the tax calculations for gasoline will make your head spin, with different rates for federal, state, county, city, etc. Sometimes the tax rate depends on how long you've had the fuel in inventory, where you shipped it from, where you shipped it to, and (I'm not kidding) the day of the week that you're delivering it on. It's maddening!

Tax rates and calculations change distressingly often for certain products. You can try to keep historical tax rate data so you can re-compute taxes and fees on previous transactions, but it's a whole lot easier and much more reliable to save what you calculated at the time.

Comment: Dear Jim, many thanks for taking the time out to reply. Your answer makes sense and also reiterates what my colleague said. The tax rates are stored in a seperate table which does therefore offers the functionality of storing the various factors for calculation as and when they are needed. However, I do believe that in the long run, you do leave yourself open to errors, especially when creating new reports.

Answer (score 1):

I would also store the entire history for the reasons stated by other posters.  However, here is a thought for you: by using SqlServer's Temporal Tables you can then design your queries to grab the various tax structures as-at the date of the transaction. This functionality is provided by the database engine with just a few extra key words to your SQL. The approach will appeal to your sense of order and correctness I am sure, but it's obviously then incumbent on you to ensure you use the feature as appropriate (it would be easy to overlook or forget). Another downside is that. Lot of reporting or ORMs don't yet support it natively, so more SQL or procedures for you.

Food for thought. You will have to decide if it's worth it (I suspect not but I don't know the details of your app)

Answer (score 0):

So this is going to depend on a few other factors.

Is this a new environment or one that has already been running for awhile? Altering db design on something currently being used is a headache. This is especially true if the `OrderItem` table is a critical part of the Inbound business processes.

If we are on a fresh db environment with no users or data to worry about, then I would say we are safe to make the change. However, we should also ask whether its a possibility that this 'historical data' will ever become 'active data' in the future.

If the this is an active db, then we need a good reason to go through the headache of altering table schema with data already associated to it. How often are we needing to hit `VatCodeID` (FK) in our current reporting processes? If the answer is 'not very often', then we can save ourselves a lot of time and a lot of money by leaving it as is.

But maybe we are using `OrderItem` quite often and it would be nice to have all our data on a flat table for a business reason. Then we should ask, can I get away with doing less and achieve a similar performance increase?

Since we checked how often that `OrderItem` was being queried while being join to whatever `VatCodeId` is referencing, then we can look up those queries and to see if they can be optimized at all. This may involve adding an index to either `OrderItem` or the reference of `VatCodeId`, that would still be preferable to altering the table structure most of the time.

Keep in mind that even after you've `altered` the tables involved and migrated the data across, that you may then have to fix any `insert` statements where a developer got lazy and wasn't as explicit as they should have been. Additionally, if a record on `OrderItem` is associated to multiple records on the table `VatCodeId` is referencing, then we may also have to through and fix the `group by` statements that are pulling from `OrderItem`.

You will then likely need to touch up any third-party reporting software that references the tables you changed because that reporting software also often requires explicit call outs.

Basically, the answer to your question is that no, we should probably leave that table as is unless we have a very good reason not. But, if we do think we have a **very** good reason, then the next step is to spend several hours researching everything else we would need to change in order to make this work.

Comment: Dear Edward,
Many thanks for taking the time to reply. I have slightly mis-worded my original question. This is a brand new application with a db from scratch. I have historical data to import but there are no stored procs or views. Everything was done on an old VB.Net app with SSRS.  I have no access to the original project or source files.  I suppose what I would like to get opinions on is whether it would be preferable to store gross / net / tax values for each line or calculate when required.  Once again, many thanks.